# How to enable the highlighting of the file "/etc/login.defs" on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, login, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

When I open the file `/etc/login.defs` on a RHEL 8.3 system, it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, it highlights the content. But when I open the same file in a Ubuntu 20.04 system, there is no highlighting.

[image]

I tried vim commands like `:syntax on`, but of no avail. How can I enable the highlighting of this file? Where is the setting that controls this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 20.04, `login.defs` syntax highlighting is handled by `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/logindefs.vim`, which is part of the `vim-runtime` package.

Your Ubuntu system probably has `vim-tiny` installed; to get this syntax highlighting, you need to install `vim` or `vim-nox` instead. These provide more complete versions of Vim, relying on `vim-runtime`. `vim` should be good enough for most uses; `vim-nox` adds scripting language support (Lua, Perl, Python 3, Ruby, Tcl).

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the same vi packages are installed on the 2 systems. Run this and compare:

```
dpkg -l 'vi*'
```

Versions might be different, but vim-tiny on it's own will not do syntax high-lighting, for instance.

Comment: RHEL uses rpm (no dpkg).  Versioning and patching will differ.  OP could do a "`:set all`" to see if the syntax is recognized, but patching makes that only part of the story.